# C# between two dates search

Tags: c#, date, datagridview, filter, warnings

I have a data (access) and I using a datetimePicker. I have nearly a thousand datas

```
Name:        Birthday:       
AAAA         05.02.2000
BBBB         01.08.1995
CCCC         04.07.1995
DDDD         05.07.1995
```

I use 2 datetimePicker and a button, datetimePicker2 first time, datetimePicker3 last time and then click filter button. I want show me datagridview on forexample 01.01.1995 - 01.12.1995 Who are they born list

I used this code:

```
private void btnFiltre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    table.Clear();
    OleDbDataAdapter adtr = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM data WHERE date BETWEEN'" + 
              dateTimePicker2.Text + "' AND '" + dateTimePicker3.Text + "'", cnn);           
    adtr.Fill(table);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

But I always take warning.

What can I do it?

Comment: What is the warning you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Many details missing, but, as usual: DO NOT use string concatenation to build sql commands.
Use a parametrized query like this

```
private void btnFiltre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    table.Clear();
    OleDbDataAdapter adtr = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM data WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?", cnn)
    adtr.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",dateTimePicker2.Value)
    adtr.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",dateTimePicker3.Value)
    adtr.Fill(table);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

Details missing:

- Which database are you using? If it is an MS-Access then the `date`
  is a reserved keyword and need to be encapsulated in square brackets
- Where do you initialize the connection? (Do not use a global connection object)
- Is your date field a datetime or a string (bad, very bad)